# Is there a way to copy URLs from all open tabs in a Google Chrome (or other browser) window into an email?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, browser-tabs

Are there any Google Chrome extensions that would allow you to copy the URLs of all open tabs into the clipboard, or even better, to send them to a new Gmail message?

My personal scenario is house hunting, opening many prospective places in separate tabs, and then wanting to send a message with all the links without copying and pasting each URL.

Answer (score 70):

Chrome, version 40 (**without** an extension):

**NOTE**: This method saves all open tabs as bookmarks in a new folder, which can then be deleted.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + d</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + Shift + d</kbd> on Mac to "Bookmark open pages".
2. Type name of folder for bookmarked pages and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + o</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ + b</kbd> on Mac to open "Bookmark Manager" (pictured below).
4. Select saved folder.
5. Give focus to folder contents pane.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + a</kbd> on Mac to select all bookmarks.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + c</kbd> on Mac to **copy all urls (and only urls)**.

[image: Chrome version 40 "Bookmark Manager"]

Comment: Works good, but entries are separated by just 0a instead of 0d 0a, so no new line between entries when viewed using Windows notepad. Anyone know of a good way to insert 0d before all of the 0a ?

Comment: @user3015682 From [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/), looking at the bottom toolbar, right-click "Unix (LF)" and select "Windows (CR LF)". From `bash` (after installing `dos2unix`), `unix2dos my_url_file.txt` . From CMD, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844521/6505499), `type my_url_file.txt | more /p > my_windows_eol_url_file.txt`. From the Notepad application ([as of 2018-05-08](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/)), it seems you can see things correctly, but not change the EOL. I'm sure there are plenty of other ways, too.

Comment: I wish there was a way to copy the titles of the pages along with the URLs. I would prefer this option over extensions that get access to your browsing history(!) or at least slow down chrome by some extent.

Answer (score 12):

Captain here

All you gotta do is type the following in the address(URL) bar in chrome

chrome://inspect/#pages

This will let you copy all of the URLs from all the open tabs into your favorite text editor. If you use something like sublime text you can remove the URLs easily with a few clicks

Flies away

Comment: One caveat: It only shows the tabs which Chrome has actively loaded.

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for!

to expand on it — if you want to copy only URLs, then you can open the console for this #pages tab and run 


`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#pages-list .row .url')).map(a => a.innerText).join(' \n')`

Answer (score 7):

With Firefox, there is the [**CopyAllURLs**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/934) add-on which does exactly that.

> copies and pastes all urls of open
>   tabs inclusive history in structured
>   and well defined form to and from
>   clipboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly, Firefox broke this extension (and many others) around the time of version 57.  [Copy All Tabs](https://pluginsaddonsextensions.com/mozilla-firefox/copy-all-tabs-mozilla-addon) is a decent replacement.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [TabCopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcopy/micdllihgoppmejpecmkilggmaagfdmb?hl=en-US), which has not been mentioned yet.  It has a higher rating than Copy All URLs, and offers more supported formats.

[image: TabCopy demo]

Comment: Nice! I found it here too: https://github.com/hansifer/TabCopy I like the "Custom" option.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Grab y'all links Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grab-yall-links/ajjloplcjllkammemhenacfjcccockde

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Tablerone extension: https://tabler.one

It exports page URLs, page meta titles, screenshot thumbnails, and your notes as:

- Plain text list
- Plain text table
- Markdown list with thumbs
- Markdown table
- HTML list with thumbs
- HTML table
- JSON
- CSV