# How to copy URLs of all open Chrome tabs without an extension

Tags: google-chrome, brave

Often when I'm using Chrome or Brave, I'd like to copy all of the URLs of my open tabs into another app such as Notepad.

I realize that many available extensions have this functionality, but I avoid installing extensions because of the security risk.

I figure there must be some native way to achieve my goal, sort of like how [How do I copy all file names in a folder to notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/490306/how-do-i-copy-all-file-names-in-a-folder-to-notepad/1588493#1588493) is a hidden way to copy file names in Windows 10.

**How can I copy all of the URLs of my open tabs *without* using an extension?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to copy URLs from all open tabs in a Google Chrome (or other browser) window into an email?](https://superuser.com/questions/117754/is-there-a-way-to-copy-urls-from-all-open-tabs-in-a-google-chrome-or-other-brow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I found an answer that worked for me on Brave Version 1.15.72 Chromium: 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit).

### All credit goes to https://superuser.com/a/877859/74576, so please upvote over there.

Chrome, version 40 (**without** an extension):

**NOTE**: This method saves all open tabs as bookmarks in a new folder, which can then be deleted.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + d</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + Shift + d</kbd> on Mac to "Bookmark open pages".
2. Type name of folder for bookmarked pages and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + o</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ + b</kbd> on Mac to open "Bookmark Manager" (pictured below).
4. Select saved folder.
5. Give focus to folder contents pane.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + a</kbd> on Mac to select all bookmarks.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>⌘ + c</kbd> on Mac to **copy all urls (and only urls)**.

[image: Chrome version 40 "Bookmark Manager"]

**Again, please upvote the original answer at https://superuser.com/a/877859/74576 instead of mine.**

Answer (score 0):

[image]Adding to the above :
Brave to Chrome or Chrome to brave can be done similarly as they are both built on same (chrome base).

go to the
[image: settings ellipsis on chrome/ hamburger on brave]

on brave/chrome

[image: on brave/chrome].

Click and select bookmarks > bookmark all tabs > create a folder X and save the tabs there.

Then do

> `Ctrl + Shift + o`

on Windows/Linux or

> `⌥ + ⌘ + b`

on Mac to open "Bookmark Manager". Select all tab links in the folder X. ctrl + C or ⌘ + C on mac. Go to the other browser. Again click the settings/ellipsis/hamburger in the browser. Select Bookmarks > Bookmarks manager > select ellipsis/hamburger > Add new folder X > select the folder X on left side of bookmarks page > paste all urls. Done.

Now all you have to do is right click the new folder in the new browser and select [image: open all tabs (you can also open all in new window if you want that)]